# How does type hinting work with Closure::call?

Tags: php, closures, php-7.0

I have created a function called `foo` which invokes a callable `\Closure` object created in `bar`.

The documentation for Closure::call() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) says that the `call` method "temporarily binds the closure to newthis, and calls it with any given parameters".

In my example I do not have any parameters, but do call the `baz` method from the object I am invoking the call. When executing the code it echos "Hello world", as expected. But, my IDE is unable to detect the `baz` method within the anoymus function and instead flags a warning: `Method baz not found in A`.

```
class A
{
    public function bar(): string
    {
        $b = new B();

        return $b->foo(function(){
            return $this->baz();
        });
    }
}

class B
{
    public function foo(\Closure $callback): string
    {
        $callback->call($this);
    }

    public function baz(): string
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

I can add something like this.

```
$b->foo(function(){
    /** @var B $this */
    return $this->baz();
});
```

However, if I run a static code analysis like php stan. Then it reports:
`Call to an undefined method A::baz().`

Therefore, my question is: How should I reference `newthis` within my anonymous function, is this even possible?

Comment: PHP 7.0 (as Q is tagged) is not supported anymore. Upgrade to a recent version is strongly recommended.

Comment: Your code is fine, I think this is just a limitation of the code analysis tool. It's doing static analysis, but `Closure::bind` and `Closure::call` allow dynamic changes to the class of `$this`.

Comment: It probably knows that `$this` isn't a real variable, so ignores the documentation comment.